# jquery keypress event object keyCode for firefox problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keypress, keycode

jQuery keypress event for FireFox gives encrypted `keyCode` property for event object 
after `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)` conversion but works perfect in Chrome.

Following is the javascript code:

```
<!-- #booter and #text are ids of html element textarea -->

<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(function(){
        $('#booter').keypress(function(e){              
            var input = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            $('#text').focus().val(input);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `e.charCode` in Firefox.

```
$("#booter").keypress(function(e){
     var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
     var input = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(code);
     $('#text').focus().val(input);
     return false;
});
```

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/REJ4t/

PS
If you're wondering why all this mess: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: Worked like a charm... Thanks :)

Comment: e.charCode || e.keyCode <= This is Perfect :)

Comment: Just be aware that according to MDN e.keyCode and e.charCode and e.which are deprecated. I was a bit amazed by that since the replacement, called e.code doesn't have proper support. It seems to only option now is e.key which has IE9 support

Answer (score 1):

It works for both IE & FF.

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

         $('#txtEntry').keypress(function (e) {

             $('#lnkValidEdit').focus();
             return false;

         });
```