# jquery 1.8 class selector not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, class, firefox, jquery-selectors

I've written a very simple class selector so that I can make html input boxes only accept numeric inputs

```
$(".numericOnly").keypress(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) return true;
   if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9]/g)) 
      return false;     
});
```

Then, if you have an input box, you just assign it class="numericOnly" and it will only accept numeric input.

keyCode 13 is the enter key, which prevents the function from intercepting and blocking it.

It works great in Chrome and oddly in IE 9, but it fails in firefox. Not sure why. There are no errors being thrown.

Comment: Use `e.charCode` with Firefox.

See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869996/jquery-keypress-event-object-keycode-for-firefox-problem

Answer (score 1):

The attribute name for the key that was pressed (`keyCode` or `charCode`) varies by browser. Try using [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead, which normalizes that for you.

Answer (score 1):

`keyCode` is set in keydown and keyup handlers.  `charCode` is set in keypress handlers, and indicates which character was entered (which is not the same thing as which key was pressed, because different keyboard layouts exist).